# WCF data dervices exception handling on client side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, wcf-data-services

I currently try to make a clean wcf data service exception handling on the wpf client. I have a simple data service with ef4 model and sql database and a wpf4 client.

I've read some articles about wcf data services exception handling and came up with a solution where I parse the received exceptions message which is a well formatted xml.

The article: [ADO.NET Data Services : Efficient Error Handling across Application Tiers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2009/11/14/ado-net-data-services-efficient-error-handling-across-application-tiers.aspx)

The problem is, my `DataServiceQueryException`'s Message contains HTML for the error page within a browser instead of XML. So the parser fails to parse a XDocument and simply returns the original exception

On the server side I throw

```
throw new DataServiceException(
    (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
    ExceptionMessages.ErrorAuthCommon);
```

Where's the mistake?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Here are some code snippets

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
         config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
```

The exception gets thrown within `CustomAuthProvider.Authenticate(application.Context)`

```
public class BasicAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest
           += new EventHandler(context_AuthenticateRequest);
    }
    void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (!CustomAuthProvider.Authenticate(application.Context))
        {
            application.Context.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
            application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            application.Context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            application.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

And here I register my `IHttpModule`

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="CustomAuthenticationModule" type="DataService.BasicAuthenticationModule">
    </modules>
</system.webServer
```

Comment: I am confused, You are trying to throw exception on service side and catch on client side ? show a bit code so we could understand better.

Comment: That's what I want to do. But on wcf data services it works a little bit different than with normal wcf service, where you can define fault contracts. After throwing a DataServiceException on wcf data services the exception gets wrapped and mapped into a DataServiceQueryException (if it is within a query). In the linked example this exceptions message property contains XML. But in my client the message property contains a html error site, which is a lot harder to parse.